# How to check if lng/lat bounding box intersects with another?

Tags: java

Assume I have several bounding boxes with 4 coordinates pair (long/lat only) each representing the 4 corners of a square box. How can I check if 2 of those boxes intersects?

I know I could use `java.awt.Rectangle` to check if 2 rectangles intersects, but the problem is it is calculated using X/Y/Width/Height instead of coordinates.

Can someone please give me some directions on how can I do this calculations?

Thanks.

#### EDIT

What I am trying to accomplish is the same represented by [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) library.

Basically it calculates a square bounding box around a given point and check if the (imaginary) squares intersects with each other, like in this image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers/MarkerClusterWithSquares.png))</sub>

So far I've been able to calculate the corners for each marker and now I need to somehow check if they intersect with each other. How can I do this intersection calculation?

#### EDIT 2

This is how I am calculating the corners:

```
private static double getLatitude(double distance, double lat, double angle) {
    return toDegrees(asin(sin(toRadians(lat)) * cos(distance / RADIUS) + cos(toRadians(lat)) * sin(distance / RADIUS) * cos(toRadians(angle))));
}

private static double getLongitude(double distance, double lat, double lng, double angle) {
    double newLat = getLatitude(distance, lat, angle);
    return toDegrees(toRadians(lng) + atan2(sin(toRadians(angle)) * sin(distance / RADIUS) * cos(toRadians(lat)), cos(distance / RADIUS) - sin(toRadians(lat)) * sin(toRadians(newLat))));
}
```

Where RADIUS = 6378.1 and angle = 45/135/225/315 (top right, bottom right, bottom left and top left).

[Example output](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-13.235004,-50.92528&zoom=10&size=900x900&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&markers=color:blue%7C-13.235004,-50.92528&path=color:334433%7Cweight:5%7Cfillcolor:0xFFFF0033%7C-13.203241505850738,-50.95790277517345%7C-13.203241505850738,-50.89265722482655%7C-13.266762353450995,-50.892648717468646%7C-13.266762353450995,-50.957911282531356%7C-13.203241505850738,-50.95790277517345)

Comment: Where are your codes ?

Comment: So far I've only coded the bounding box generation, which gives me the four corners coordinates . I don't know how to continue from here, so I haven't coded the intersection part.

Comment: It is too broad so far.

Comment: I've added another explanation to see if it better explains what I need.

Comment: Bear in mind that it makes a difference how you define "intersect". There are no straight lines on the surface of a sphere, so if you define the lines of your rectangles to be "straight" in lat/long space they are actually curved in real life. So whether or not boxes intersect depends on how you account for those curves.

Comment: @DanielPryden I've updated the question to include how I calculate the corners. I only need that they intersects on the map, not in real life, so I the intersection can consider straight lines, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that in your "lat/long bounding box' each side follows the lines of constant longitude and latitude - in other words that the top side follows the line of constant latitude, and the left side the line of constant longitude.

While this is not actually a rectangle in real life, it can actually be treated as one for our purposes. Mathematically you can think of this as transforming the bounding box into a "lat/long' space, where the shape is in fact a rectangle. If that doesn't make sense you may have to take my word for it. In any case it is possible to show that the curved shapes in real space intersect if and only if the rectangles intersect in curved space.

The short version of this is: **if you do a standard test for intersection of rectangles** (using the Java Rectangle class code, and using latitude and longitude as the rectangle bounds) **you will get the right result.**

**EXAMPLE**

You have two areas, defined as:

1. The area between 50 and 52 degrees N and 75 and 77 degrees E
2. The area between 51 and 53 degrees N and 76 and 79 degrees E

You can correctly test for their intersection by doing:

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(75,50,2,2);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(76,51,2,3);
boolean intersects = r1.insersects(r2);
```

It doesn't matter that the rectangles are not rectangular in Euclidean space.

P.S. This will not work if one of your rectangles actually contains either the north or south pole. In that case you will need to split each rectangle into two, one on each side of the pole. You need to normalize everything to +/- 90 latitude and +/- 180 longitude. You will need to do something clever if one or more of the rectangles overlaps the +/-180 longitude line.

Comment: Can I assume the boundaries are the topLeft long and bottomRight lat? Width and Height should be the haversine distance between topLeft/topRight?

Comment: top and bottom should be latitude and left and right should be longitude. Width and height should both be in degrees.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. How to I get the width/height in degress? Is it the haversine boundary distance ?

Comment: No, it's just lat2-lat1 and long2-long1.

Comment: How do you choose between the lats/longs to pass to the Rectangle class? Like, why did you choose 75 and not 77 on the first Rectangle? Or can I choose any of them, since I am passing height and width as well?

Comment: Always pass the lower of the numbers to the constructor. Rectangle(52,77,2,2) would be a rectangle from 52-54 and 77 -79.